# Create XSD based on root element

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xsd

I have a XSD as shown below , i need to extract all the root Elements in the XSD and create a separate XSD for each root element pragmatically in java, is there some framework of java library that can aid me in achieving this.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.org" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="HouseNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="OrderType">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="orderID" type="xsd:string"/>
         <xsd:element name="billTo" type="USAddress"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="Customer">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CustomerID" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Address" type="USAddress"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
   <xsd:element name="Order" type="OrderType"/>
</xsd:schema>
```

TO

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.org" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="HouseNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:complexType name="OrderType">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="orderID" type="xsd:string"/>
         <xsd:element name="billTo" type="USAddress"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="Order" type="OrderType"/>
</xsd:schema>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='windows-1252'?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.example.org" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org" elementFormDefault="qualified">
   <xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
      <xsd:sequence>
         <xsd:element name="HouseNumber" type="xsd:string"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
   </xsd:complexType>
   <xsd:element name="Customer">
      <xsd:complexType>
         <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="CustomerID" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="Address" type="USAddress"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:complexType>
   </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

Comment: What is the purpose of this exercise?

Comment: Note that a XML would be valid if it is valid against any of the "root" <xs:element> (not only the first one). Is that your problem?

Comment: @laune the purpose of this exercise is to make sure each XSD has only one root element , which i need to refer in my RAML(REST service specification) specification

Comment: @sergioFC my problem is to create each XSD with exactly one root element , i don't have to validate any XML against it.

Comment: In this case, rewrite the XSD, eliminating all root elements, define complexTypes from the inline types (as with `<xsd:element name="Customer">`). Then, write one schema for each root element, including the schema cleaned-up in step 1. I bet that this is less effort than writing the transformation you're planning.

Comment: @laune thanks for the suggestion , it makes lot of sense , is there any framework that can help me do this.

Comment: I think that doing this manually is the best approach. There aren't hundreds of root elements, are there?

Comment: no there are only few elements , but i want it to be done pragmatically in java

Comment: Well, good luck: it means that you'll have to write a rather complicated program.

Comment: :( , by the way thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: Are you familiar with XSL? Maybe you can use it

Comment: @sergioFC thank you for your time for developing the working code , i did ran it and it works as you have explained , i am new to XSL so need some time to get my head around it, What changes should i make in xsl.xsl to keep all the types in the same file instead of extracting it to a separate schema_types.xsd , it does not matter if its duplicated in each generated file.This solution definitely has provided me direction , thank you once again.

Comment: You're welcome. Actually, XSL is so simple and powerful that writting it only tooks some minutes. @laune I've finally implemented your good idea using XSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using *XSL 2.0* you can have multiple output documents and can define every file name, file content, etc. Default *java* support for *XSL 2.0* is far from perfect, so I use the incredible *[Saxon](http://www.saxonica.com/welcome/welcome.xml)* (you can download *saxon-he* [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.6/SaxonHE9-6-0-6J.zip/download), unzip it and add *saxon9he.jar* to your project).

This is the example XSL 2.0 I've made, it works using the idea that user [laune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2107876/laune) has exposed in [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30843304/create-xsd-based-on-root-element#comment49745708_30843304). So it produces one output schema for every element, and a schema for everything that is not an element (types). Every new schema contains only a *xs:element*'s and has a *xs:include* including the schema containing types. It is a quite simple (and very clever in my opinion) method and easy to understand if you're familiar with XSL (look at the xsl comments).

xsl.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="/*/*[local-name()='element']">
            <xsl:variable name="currentElement" select="."/>
            <!-- Create schema for every element containing only element, including types schema -->
            <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="schema_element_{@name}.xsd">
                <xsl:for-each select="/*[1]">
                    <xsl:copy>
                        <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                        <xsl:element name="include" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
                            <xsl:attribute name="schemaLocation">schema_types.xsd</xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:element> <!-- Include clause -->
                        <xsl:copy-of select="$currentElement"/> <!-- Only content is current xs:element -->
                    </xsl:copy>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>

        <xsl:for-each select="/*[1]">
            <!-- Create types document containing all but root xs:element's -->
            <xsl:result-document method="xml" href="schema_types.xsd">
                <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="node()[local-name()!='element']"/>
                </xsl:copy>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The only java code needed is for calling *saxon* to do the xsl transformation that produce the output files with the names dynamically derived in *xsl*.

Main.java

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamSource;

public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[]args) throws Exception{
        TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("xsl.xsl")));
        transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File("schema.xsd")), new StreamResult(System.out));
    }
}
```

Using your example schema, my xsl and running the java code these are the files that will be created with these filenames (note that indentation might be lost):

schema_element_Customer.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <include xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        schemaLocation="schema_types.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="Customer">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="CustomerID" type="xsd:string" />
                <xsd:element name="Address" type="USAddress" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

schema_element_Order.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <include xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
        schemaLocation="schema_types.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="Order" type="OrderType" />
</xsd:schema>
```

schema_types.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="http://www.example.org" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="HouseNumber" type="xsd:string" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:complexType name="OrderType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="orderID" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:element name="billTo" type="USAddress" />
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

### UPDATE: necessary changes to output to Map

Necessary changes to output to Map instead of files in the file-system:

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10855640/3870761) I realized that you can add a setting to be notified by every *result-document* so you can writte the output where you want implementing an [OutputUriResolver](http://www.saxonica.com/documentation9.5/javadoc/net/sf/saxon/lib/OutputURIResolver.html). So I've made this one that writes to a HashMap:

```
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import net.sf.saxon.lib.OutputURIResolver;

public class HashMapSaverOutputUriResolver implements OutputURIResolver{
    private Map<String, String> results; // We save here
    public HashMapSaverOutputUriResolver(Map<String, String> map){
        this.results = map; // Set map
    }
    public OutputURIResolver newInstance() {
        return this;
    }
    public Result resolve(String href, String base) throws TransformerException { // We set to resolve the file to write to a stringResult that wraps a stringWritter
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); // StringWritter 
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(sw); // StreamResult
        sr.setSystemId(href); // Id of the streamResult = href = fileName
        return sr;
    }
    public void close(Result result) throws TransformerException { // End of result:document transformed
        StreamResult sr = (StreamResult) result; // Get StreamResult
        StringWriter sw = (StringWriter) sr.getWriter(); // Get StreamWritter
        String href = sr.getSystemId(); // Get href (fileName)
        String content = sw.toString(); // Get string file-content
        this.results.put(href, content); // Save in map
    }
}
```

In the main file you only need to add two new lines (create the map, and set the proper setting to the OutputUriResolver associated with the map).

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    HashMap<String, String> results = new HashMap<String, String>(); // Your map        
    TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    tFactory.setAttribute("http://saxon.sf.net/feature/outputURIResolver", new HashMapSaverOutputUriResolver(results)); // Set OutputURIResolver
    Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new File("xsl.xsl")));
    transformer.transform(new StreamSource(new File("schema.xsd")), new StreamResult(System.out));
    // Once the transformation has finished the Map is filled
}
```

Comment: After some reading i made some changes to your XSL file and was able to get the required output . thanks a lot

Comment: You're welcome again. If you want feel free to update my answer or make a new one based on this one. I think the finally XSL you got it is even shorter than the original.

Comment: yes the final XSL i got is shorter than the original one.

Comment: @user2478236 Well, I might have proposed an XSLT solution except for OP's explicit (!) demand for Java. + to sergioFC for knowing better.

Comment: @sergioFC One question , can we output this to a hash map instead of file , like Map<key,value> where is key is file name and value is XSD as string

Comment: According to this XSL the output should be files. This can be changed, generally XSL output is a string or a unique document. I think it is easier to change the XSL than the saxon library source. Another option is to read the generated files and save them in your Map.

Comment: @user2478236 Let me know if you need help with it.

Comment: I understood this "read the generated files and save them in your Map". If i can get string output instead of document , it will be easier to load it to map , instead of saving to a document and the reading it. Since there are multiple documents generated what XSL changes can help me achieve this.

Comment: @user2478236 I've realized that there is no need to change the XSL as it is possible to resolve the URIs as you want, redirecting output to StringWriter instead of File. I've updated it in my answer.